# Decompressing compressed data

Tags: c#, base64, compression

I am trying to decompress some compressed data that is populated in a `List<string>`. Here is my Decompress method:

```cs
static string Decompress(string inputStr)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    string decompressedString = string.Empty;
    byte[] compressedBytes = new byte[0];

    try
    {
        compressedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(inputStr);
    }
    catch
    {
        failedDecompressionCnt++;
    }
    
    using (var compressedStream = new MemoryStream(compressedBytes))
    using (var decompressedStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var gzip = new GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int read;
        while ((read = gzip.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            decompressedStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }

        byte[] decompressedBytes = decompressedStream.ToArray();
        decompressedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decompressedBytes);
    }
    result.Append(decompressedString);
    return result.ToString();
}
```

I put a breakpoint on this line in the `try` block:

> ```cs
> compressedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(inputStr);
> ```

and the `catch` block was executed for for the following `inputStr`:

```
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1
```

I get an exception on this line in my `Decompress` method: `byte[] compressedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(inputStr);`.

The exception is as follows:

> System.FormatException: 'The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.'

I am iterating through a list of compressed data and passing each entry to my `Decompress` method one by one and most of the compressed data is decompressed correctly and I do not get this error. I only get this error on some of the compressed data. I do not understand how this is possible for some of the compressed data only if I compressed all the data in the same way. Out of a list of around 52000 entries, I get about 1500 failed decompressions with the exception mentioned above.

I am still relatively a noobie and I am trying to understand how it is possible to decompress most of the data correctly if all of the data was compressed in the same way?

Just for some additional context I am compressing the data as follows:

```cs
static string Compress(string inputStr, long cnt)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    byte[] inputStrBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputStr);
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var gzip = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        gzip.Write(inputStrBytes, 0, inputStrBytes.Length);
        gzip.Close();

        byte[] compressed = stream.ToArray();
        result.Append(Convert.ToBase64String(compressed));
        Console.WriteLine(cnt);
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

I tried to decompress the data as previously mentioned but it was giving me the previously mentioned exception.

Comment: your code executes fine for me with your provided base64 string!

Comment: Your code works fine on the provided data: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qOG4vC

Comment: What is the source of the compressed data?  Where does it come from?

Comment: I get the data from a column in my PostgreSQL DB table. This column contains compressed data which I am trying to decompress.

I have also updated the description because the original compressed string I provided was maybe incorrect. The new on in the description definitely causes the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Base64 string has an extraneous `1` at the end, after the equal sign. Not sure how that got there, but get rid of it. Then the Base-64 decoding gives a valid gzip stream.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mark, this was the issue indeed.